# load different page depending on frame suport

Tags: html, apache, frames

I have a simple frameset which works fine and when frames arnt supported it shows a link to the frame free version. What I would like is for the page to redirect to the frame free version if the browser doesn't support frames. I have googled without success and I am sure it can be done but as yet I haven't worked out. Ideas please?

Comment: Yes i realise this was an appalling question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use 'Browser Sniffing' and blacklist those without support however this is generally a bad idea.

Also you should avoid using frames are they have been dropped from HTML5 and are an accessibility nightmare

Use either CSS positioning or iframes to achieve similar results